# Duplicate page without canonical tag excluded from Google Index

Tags: seo, google-search-console, rel-canonical

In the Google Search Console I see a section under `Index Coverage` that shows a ton of URLS that have been excluded from the index with a status of `Duplicate page without canonical tag`.

Here is an example url:

```
https://www.example.com/elliptical-drive-belt&brand=Lifespan&product_type=Treadmill&category=Motor%20Control%20Boards
```

This page can also be accessed just by going to this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/elliptical-drive-belt
```

The parameters in the first URL allow the user to filter search results or defin their search further. How do I go about fixing this? Should I use the following code to create a cannonical reference from the page that has parameters to the one that doesn't? The 2 pages contain different information:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/elliptical-drive-belt" />
```

Comment: It sounds like Google is already fixing the problem for you.  It is identifying nearly duplicate pages and choosing one to index.  Unless you don't like which one Google is choosing, you may not have to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Google how to treat paramters in your URLs here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters?hl=en&authuser=0&siteUrl=

If you want Google to better understand your parameters and how to adjust your indexing based on them, I highly recommend that you add all of them to that page in the webmaster console.

Using `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/elliptical-drive-belt" />` in your pages with '&' parameters will greatly help Google know how to treat these (semi-duplicate) pages.